# iOS 9.3 Deployment Target

Tags: ios

The current deployment target for my app is 8.0.  When iOS 10 comes out I'd like to bump the deployment target to 9.3.

- What would happen to the users of my app below 9.3?
- What would happen to someone who would like to download my app but is below 9.3?

Comment: You can let the download available for old versions for low OS versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What would happen to the users of my app below 9.3?

They wouldn't receive any more updates to the application.

> What would happen to someone who would like to download my app but is below 9.3?

There's an option in iTunes Connect you can enable in order to allow them to download the most recent version of your application that supports the version of iOS they are using.  If you don't enable this, they are shown an error message saying that your application isn't compatible with their version of iOS.